# Angular 2: Load different versions of the libraries based on the data

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular2-modules, angular-library

I have a requirement where I need to load different version modules based on the data.

Something like monthly data, if some change happens in my module code for the current month, there shouldn't be any change in the view/logic from the previous month page, the data remains same and so the view as well.

I am planning to create custom libraries for each module with the versions. With this, I can map my data with the module version.

Since my app is big and involves so many modules and versions, I cannot carry all the versions of the module/library to the client with the bundle.

Can someone suggest a better way to handle this requirement?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear on what you're attempting to accomplish. Example strategies you've considered, example code you've implemented, or even a higher level of elaboration will help. Without more information it's unlikely this question will be able to be answered.

Comment: Can you give more information about Loading different versions of Libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little ambiguous, specifically the  title. What I understood you like to load different part of your angular app based to need. You can divide the app in multiple module and load based on your need. You may take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@ct7/angular2-module-architecture-and-example-seed-project-35b7410264f5)
Please clarify if you are looking for something else.